# Celery tasks running multiple times in Django application

Tags: django, kubernetes, celery, celerybeat

For weeks now we have been having issues with tasks running multiple times (always twice actually). I have tried to reproduce this locally and did a lot of testing on our staging and production server, but I can not seem to reproduce it and find the issue. Right now I simply have no clue where to look.

-We have recently upgraded from celery v4 to v5, but this was together with many other upgrades.

-The issues are only with long running periodic tasks (celery beat) that takeabout 15 min. to complete.

-We run celery in a managed kubernetes environment with separate deployments for beat and worker. Both deployments currently have a single pod.

One example of a task running twice:

```py
@idempotent_notification_task(notification_tag='CREDITS_DIRECTDEBIT_PAYMENT')
def create_directdebit_payments_for_credits():
    plus_admin_ids = Order.objects.filter(
        subscription__type=Subscription.PLUS, credits_auto_top_up_amount__gt=0).values_list('administration_id',
                                                                                            flat=True)
    admins = Administration.objects.filter(id__in=plus_admin_ids)
    for admin in admins:
        remaining_credits = admin.remaining_credits
        if remaining_credits < 0:
            po_exists = PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(administration=admin,
                                                     created__date=today(),
                                                     service=PurchaseOrder.SERVICE.CREDITS).exists()
            if po_exists:
                print(f"PurchaseOrder for client {admin.title} already exists!")
                return

            purchase_order = PurchaseOrder.objects.create(
                administration=admin, service=PurchaseOrder.SERVICE.CREDITS,
                credits_amount=admin.order.first().credits_auto_top_up_amount)
            payment = create_credits_mollie_payment_directdebit(purchase_order)
            Notification.create_credits_directdebit_payment(purchase_order)
```

In an attempt to create a fix I created a wrapper function to make the task idempotent, but even this did not fix the issue. The wrapper function works as expected during local testing, but I still see the objects in the task being created twice.

```py
def idempotent_notification_task(notification_tag):
    """
    Decorator function that makes the celery task related to a notification template idempotent
    """
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nt = NotificationTemplate.objects.select_for_update().get(tag=notification_tag)
            with atomic():
                if nt.last_sent is not None and nt.last_sent.date() == today():
                    print(f"Notification {notification_tag} already sent today")
                    return
                else:
                    function()
                    nt.last_sent = now()
                    nt.save()
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

One weird thing that I can not wrap my head around is that sometimes I see multiple tasks being received in the celery logs. Sometimes I see one task received and sometimes I can not find the logs of the tasks at all, but they are still executed.

Comment: Is any of this setup specific to Kubernetes?  If you have the same long-running Celery task on a local-developer setup, do you see the same duplicate tasks?  Does this only happen on tasks that run longer than 15 minutes?

Comment: Well, the thing is, I can not reproduce the issue locally, but I can't reproduce the behaviour on staging either, which is running on Kubernetes. The issue happens only with longer running tasks yes, but when I create test task that runs for 30 mins, the issue does not happen. Frankly I have no clue at the moment.